# Appending only existing string/values in StringBuilder using extension

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have this method, this works as expected, it does not insert `<string, value>` if string is empty, however I have an issue where the string does't always exists. I want to avoid appending anything if string does not exists.

```
public static class StringBuilderExtension
{
    public static void AppendIfNotNull<TValue>(this StringBuilder sb, TValue value, string prefix)
        where TValue : class 
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            sb.Append(prefix + value);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is I am always passing the string key

```
sb.AppendIfNotNull(" width=\"", component.style.width + "\"");
```

This will appear as `width=""` as I physically appended the string. How can I stop this from happening.

I can stop it from appear if I wrap it around an if statement

```
if (item.width!= null)
{
    sb.AppendIfNotNull(" width=\"", item.width + "\"");
}
```

Object example. Property might exists in one object but might not on the next. e.g. Do not append color if it does not exists:

```
{
    'id': 'Test',
    'type': 'Text',
    'style': {
        'color': 'black'
        'textSize': '12'
    }
},
        {
    'id': 'Test',
    'type': 'Text',
    'style': {
        'textSize': '12'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really wondering (after seeing the follow up questions), what it is you want to achieve, so what is the goal of adding this all to your string builder? Are you doing any kind of serialization at a later time?

Comment: What is `string(key)`? I don't see a `key` anywhere. It sounds like you just don't want to append the value if it's an empty string. You could just do `var valueToAppend = value?.ToString();` and then `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueToAppend)) sb,Append(prefix + valueToAppend);`

Comment: Can you still add what your eventual output would be and what you would use it for? It almost sounds like using `XElement` might throw away all of your problems. Are you eventually generating XML? If that is the case, it might be interesting to look at other ways to handle that, than using a stringbuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply change your add from a `string prefix` to a function that takes in `TValue` and returns you a `string`

```
public static class StringBuilderExtension
{
    public static void AppendIfNotNull<TValue>(this StringBuilder sb, TValue value, Func<TValue, string> transform)
        where TValue : class 
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            sb.Append( transform( value ));
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, your transform will only be called when you are actually having a valid value

A sample way of using it could be

```
sb.AppendIfNotNull( token.style?.width, value => $" width=\"{value}\"" );
```

Where the `?` implies a conditional null check (so if `token.style` is null, it would also be null)

I added a small sample to a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VbzIQP) where I did remove the generic type restriction ( because I was throwing numbers in ;) )

Comment: I am appending it on a different method sb.AppendIfNotNull(" width=\"", item.width + "\""); With this new method do I simply call it sb.AppendIfNotNull(item.width) is this correct?

Comment: @Mask-dCodex I added how you should call it, I hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks Ice, just a few questions. The value i am obtaining is from a strongly typed object and if e.g. width doesnt exists in that object shouldnt it be token.style.width? and also I have tried to call that method but it is throwing There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter transform

Comment: @Mask-dCodex I did add a small sample to .net fiddle. Note that this doesn't support C# 6 features like conditional null check or string interpolation using $ prefix

Comment: Just a question. If Style was a list of would that imply that style? needs to be completely null in order not to add width? or is it only checking if width exists?

Comment: @Mask-dCodex If `style` was a list, that would imply that your list has a property called `width`. And yes, if in that case the list was `null`, it wouldn't check the property either. However, if you want to get to an item with the property `width`, that would be a different scenario :)

Comment: Thanks I think I understand. So For example 1 object does not have width in the style then it will not append however in the next object in style there is a width this would mean it will append width. Correct? Sorry just double checking

Comment: @Mask-dCodex Yeah, if it is null it won't be added (and it doesn't have anything to do with the conditional null check) :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers Ice. Can I ask how I can change this to handle both int/strings? As adding ToString() to my object value completely breaks my object mapping(brings back incorrect value or quotes wrong key string) not sure why

Comment: @Mask-dCodex just remove the type restriction to class as in the dotnetfiddle link I posted. The other thing you are talking about is a bit harder, as I don't know what you plan to do with your result in the end (not part of the question)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with the current method signature, but you could separately pass the prefix, your value, and suffix:

```
public static void AppendIfNotNull<TValue>(this StringBuilder sb, TValue value, string prefix, string suffix)
    where TValue : class 
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        sb.Append(prefix + value + suffix);
    }
}

sb.AppendIfNotNull(item.width, " width=\"", "\"");
```

Comment: That really adds up after a while :)